# Any way to change the "Cancel and return" label in PayPal payment page when using adaptive payments?

Tags: php, paypal, label, paypal-adaptive-payments

We're using PayPal adaptive payments API to create chained payments.

Basically the payment chain looks like this:

Buyer > Seller > Our account (We are the PayPal app owners)

We use the Pay and SetPaymentOptions operations to create the payment and set some data (like the name of the seller or a logo image).

However the PayPal payment page still says "Cancel payment and return to OUR BUSINESS NAME".

We want to change the OUR BUSINESS NAME part to something else. Basically so that the Buyer would not get confused.

Is there any way to customise the "Cancel payment" label (or at least the merchant name in it) using PayPal adaptive payments?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

No, this is the company name of your PayPal business account. There is no way to change it.

You can only specify the message on the page when the payment is confirmed, please see the [cbt parameter](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately the cbt param is used in HTML form. It's not an adaptive payments API parameter. And you're right. It's not the label I'm trying to change.